# Moving h3 tag inside next div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a set of things being outputted like this:

```
<h3>X</h3>
<div>
    <p>xxxxx</p>
</div>
<h3>Y</h3>
<div>
    <p>yyyyy</p>
</div>
<h3>Z</h3>
<div>
    <p>zzzzz</p>
</div>
```

I want to turn it into:

```
<div>
    <h3>X</h3>
    <p>xxxxx</p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Y</h3>
    <p>yyyyy</p>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Z</h3>
    <p>zzzzz</p>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I tried this:

```
$('h3').next('div').prepend();
```

But didn't work, help please.

Comment: You should show a fiddle, this is somehow unclear

Comment: Sorry I was being silly I figured it out:
`$('h3').each(function(){`
  `nextDiv = $(this).next('div');`
  `nextDiv.prepend($(this));`
 `});`

Comment: post your  own answer then and accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$('h3').each(function(){
 div = $(this).next('div');
 div.append($(this));
 $(this).remove();
});
```